# Can I use a variable int value inside of another variable function?

Tags: android, variables, actionscript-3, integer

I have a pretty basic knowledge of AS3, so I'm not sure if this is actually possible, or if it is, how to do it. I am in the very starts of coding this project, so I don't actually have much code to show, but would like to figure this issue out before I start writing everything around it.

I am making a game similar to Monopoly, so I will speak in terms of that. Basically, I want 4 Players all with variable integers that reflect how much money they have. In my game, I want to be able to click on a player, click "Buy Property", and then click the property they're buying, which would be a button (btnProperty1).

Let's say Property 1 also has a purchase value, which could be "valueProperty1", and let's say the value is 100. My players will start with 1000, so I want the buying of this property to deduct 100 from the active player money. The player money int could be "moneyPlayer1, moneyPlayer2, etc.". So, I would be able to click `btnPlayer1`, `btnBuyProperty`, `btnProperty1`, and then moneyPlayer1 would go from 1000 to 900. To determine the active player, I had the idea of making an "activePlayer" int, and just setting it to 1, 2, 3 or 4 based on which `btnPlayer` I click.

In a shotty way of putting it, I could put in the btnProperty1 `if (activePlayer == 1){moneyPlayer1 -= valueProperty1}` and write four statements, one for each player. HOWEVER, I would like to subvert doing that by writing a function that looks like this:

```
 moneyPlayer[activePlayer] -= valueProperty1 (if the activePlayer int is equal to 1, then it would fill in 1 to the end of moneyPlayer, therefor targeting moneyPlayer1)
```

In theory, it would then deduct money from whichever player is active. IF THIS IS POSSIBLE, I have no idea how to write it.

Additionally, I would like to do something similar if a subsequent player lands on an owned property. So in the same vein, I would want something that looks like this:

```
moneyPlayer[activePlayer] -= rentProperty1 (the rent value is deducted from the active player)

moneyPlayer[paidPlayer] += rentProperty1 (the rent value is added to the paid player)
```

I can figure out ways to make the active player and paid player functions work, I just need to know if I can put these variables INSIDE of other variables, so I don't have to write 18,748 if statements.

Lastly, I would love to be able to enter a player name into an input text field, then have it appear in a dynamic text field. I tried looking around and couldn't find an answer... So bonus points for this one :)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: Your interpretation seems fine. Making an Array or Vector of ints where the index corresponds to a different player will work in the syntax you used (`moneyPlayer[currentPlayer] -= valueProperty1`). I'd recommend making a Player class though instead with a `money` value and having a static `currentPlayer` property so you can change the current Player's money by doing `Player.currentPlayer.money -= valueProperty1`. That way if you want the players to have further functionality beyond just money you'll be able to easily add it to their class.

Comment: You actually need to plan architecture of your game, and I advise you to use classes, say `Player` or `Property`. A property can have value, owner, upgrade level, and a picture, for example, a player can have money, property list, map position, maybe more. So when you want a player to buy or check if he can buy an empty property, you just write one piece of code (a method for `Player` class that accepts a `Property`) and just ignore visibility issues. AND, ignore typo issues, to not accidentally deduce money from player 2 instead of player 1 when buying, for example.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, YES you can put variables "inside" another variable, this is called "classes" in AS3, and is a required thing to use whenever you plan something big. Say you want a `Player` class, then you can do like this:

```
public class Player {
    private var _money:int;
    ... // whatever else a player has
    public function get money:int { return _money;} // a property
    // such functions are the way to make someone not directly steal the player's money, 
    // but are a way to view the money of a player
    // rest of property functions goes here
    public function Player() // a constructor, required
    {
        _money=1000; // starting money
        ... //etc, place default values everywhere
    }
    public function earnMoney(amount:int) // makes the player able to earn money
    {
        _money += amount; // negative money may be accepted, learn to check parameters!
    }
    // everything else goes here
}
```

Then you add there more functions that can change a player's state, say a function `buy(aProperty):Boolean` that would return true if the player did buy that property, and will also change the variables "inside" both the property involved and the player (`this`, or just call variables as if they are local).

You can do way more with classes, please read about object-oriented programming, there's a lot of basics that can help you draw your game's architecture. Learn about "encapsulation" first, to not accidentally break your objects. An example was shown above.

Comment: Please add the explanation about OOP to your answer, because it is literally what the question is about.

Comment: @Organis what exactly do you want me to add here? OOP is a discipline people learn for several years in high school (we had two), it's language independent at the very least, and its basics are illustrated here already.

Comment: We don't know if that person knows of OOP. Assuming the nature of the question — probably not. Adding something like "*...hey, what you are asking for is OOP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming so how lucky we could be that AS3 is an OOP language...*" is just a good thing to do before the actual answer/example you provide.